# Is it neccessary to use LDAP with fabric-ca if i'm using postgres as a database?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

Is it neccessary to use LDAP with fabric-ca if i'm using postgres as a database (for production level )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all. There is no relationship between both configurations.

Comment: if i'd been using sqlite3 as a db then it was neccessary ?

Comment: No. Neither it is. You configure LDAP in your Fabric-CA when you want to work with your LDAP identities so that you don't need to register them, they are imported directly from LDAP. It is easy to connect but a little bit difficult to map attributes. It is not related at all with the database backend.

Comment: so if I'm using POSTGRES  i am ready to go on production without LDAP, yes i was able to connect ldap but when mapping attributes i was facing lot of difficulties so switched to postgres.

Comment: It is not easy, of course. I will use Postgres  always in production, with or without LDAP.